# Spoofing window.navigator.userAgent delay when using chrome.runtime.sendMessage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

From a Chrome Extension that executes a content script (document_start) I run:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({agent: "ask"}, function(response) { CA(response.answer); });

function CA(agent) 
{
    var Agent = "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', { value:'"+agent+"' });";
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = Agent;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
 }
```

But because of the time it takes to get a response from sendMessage,
if you load an html page that does the following ... it fails (see below):

```
var x = 0;
console.log(navigator.userAgent);
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
console.log(navigator.userAgent); if (++x === 5) { window.clearInterval(intervalID); }
}, 1);
```

The output is something like this:

```
16:31:37.515 [..] Chrome/64.0.3282.168 Safari/537.36 OPR/51.0.2830.40
16:31:37.606 [..] Chrome/64.0.3282.168 Safari/537.36
16:31:37.607 [..] Chrome/64.0.3282.168 Safari/537.36
16:31:37.608 [..] Chrome/64.0.3282.168 Safari/537.36
16:31:37.610 [..] Chrome/64.0.3282.168 Safari/537.36
16:31:37.615 [..] Chrome/64.0.3282.168 Safari/537.36
```

First line is the default userAgent from the browser, and subsequent lines
is the modified userAgent from my extension ...

Is there a way to fix this sendMessage delay so that a simple console.log(navigator.userAgent); on a webpage will see the spoofed userAgent right away?

UPDATE:

Also tried from background page like this:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(details)
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('here3')", runAt: "document_start"})
});

chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('here2')", runAt: "document_start"});
});
```

It gets executed in the following order, here2, here1, here3

(here1 being printed from the content script, and here2 & here3 from background.

However, Object.defineProperty cannot re-define window.navigator from the background page it appears - but no errors are thrown!

UPDATE:

I was able to work around this issue by setting a cookie from the background page and then reading the value from the content script.

As suggested by the comment below! Thanks :)

Comment: It's possible to set a unique cookie header in the background page using webRequest API, then your content script will have the data immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using cookies, see above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid the sendMessage delay as its an async operation.

However you could accomplish what you want to do by doing this completely in a background script in the extension rather than using the content script. What you need to do would be

1. Detect opening of tabs using chrome.tabs api
2. Once there is a tab, attach to the tab with chrome.debugger (possible commands are https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger, more than enough to run code in page to query things and to make changes in the page)
3. If you detect the userAgent needs to be changed it, do it via the chrome.debugger api (you can even optionally pause the script execution in the page to make sure the code via debugger runs first)